# HVAC tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags

With HVAC, we have a lot of potential tags, so before taking my own guess at what the wiki's should say, I thought I'd solicit the group.  Here's a list of the current tags that I think could use some clarification, and my best guess of how we should be using them:

General topics, good for broad searches and followers:
[hvac](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hvac)[heating](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heating)[air-conditioning](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning)

Questions referring to a central system (perhaps hvac belongs here):
[central-heating](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-heating)[central-air](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-air)

Questions related to a specific component/device:
[furnace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/furnace)[boiler](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boiler)[heat-pump](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat-pump)[air-conditioner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioner)[blower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blower)[thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermostat)[radiator](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiator)

Miscellaneous:
[forced-air](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forced-air)

If everyone is in agreement with this, then I can start by updating the wiki's to help differentiate the furnace from the central heating system, and the air conditioner from air conditioning, etc.  Then I'll slowly retag some of the older questions (so that new questions aren't lost in a sea of edits).  Of course any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me.

It occurred to me that "cooling" would be a good synonym for "air-conditioning", so much so that I retagged the [A/C escaping down the staircase](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6645/22) question, intending to propose it.  However, I forgot that under the new synonym system, I'd need a score of 5 in the tag (which I don't have) so someone else will have to do it if they think it's a good synonym.

I took a quick look through the tags related to energy sources and it seems to me that they're being used accurately and descriptively.  Some thoughts from my trawl:

- [natural-gas](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-gas) (2 questions) is a synonym for [gas](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas) (18 questions) but I don't have the rep to propose it.
- 1 question tagged [oil-burner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-burner)
- 3 questions tagged [woodstove](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woodstove)
- 3 questions tagged with both [[electrical] and [heating]](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical+heating), two of which could reasonably be retagged with a new [electric-heating](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-heating) tag:

  1. [What types of flooring can be used with electric radiant heat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5942/22)
  2. [Should I switch from propane to electric heat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3738/22)

Comment: I missed cooling, only went through several pages of the tags to make this list.  Thanks!  And I'm facing the same problem trying to create synonyms.

Comment: You didn't miss it; I created it while writing this answer expressly to make it a synonym.

Comment: @B Mitch & Niall - if there's any that you think need doing urgently flag a post for moderator attention. They'll be able to set up the synonym. However, it would be work waiting until there's a consensus on what the synonyms should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you need anything batch retagged by a moderator, just let me know -- we can magically change or remove tags *en masse* without bumping anything.

Comment: I'm guessing there won't be a lot of *en masse* work for this, more like removing an extra air-conditioner tag on a question when the AC unit is fine and they want to know more about air-conditioning in general.  But good to know this option exists.